# Scraping music playlist info from a website

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I am trying to scrape the names of artists and songs from the online playlog of a a daily radio show I like. I'd like to eventually use that scraped data to use python to compile a playlist on Spotify or Youtube.

Why won't my code retrieve and print all the songs?

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup # latest version bs4

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen("http://music.cbc.ca/#!/The-Signal").read(), 'lxml')

song = soup.find_all("span", {'class': 'logTrackTitle'})

print song
```

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxEet.png)

Comment: Please copy paste your code into your question

Comment: Thanks, done. Feedback appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Snooping around the page using the Chrome DevTools, you'll see that the 'Broadcast Log' section of the page is actually an iframe with a different URL. That's where the list of songs is "coming from".

Swapping the iframe's URL into your code correctly returns the songs.

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup # latest version bs4

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen("http://music.cbc.ca/The-Signal").read(), 'lxml')

song = soup.find_all("span", {'class': 'logTrackTitle'})

print song
```